# Create a formula including nth values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say i want to use this formula `"(x1*m1+x2*m2...+xi*mi)/m_tot"` in excel. Where "xi" is found in every 6th row and "mi" is found in every 6th row in another comlumn. "m_tot" is the sum of all the "mi" values.
Does anybody know a smart way to do this?
There are a lot of rows so its a struggle to type everything manually.

Comment: It would help if you could show an example of your data and formulae so far, preferably as text. You can [edit] your question and use the formatting tools to include the relevant information.

Comment: Could you provide a sample..

Comment: It isn't clear what the input and output should look like. Can you please edit your post and copy-and-paste a screenshot image example into you post?

Answer (score 0):

One simple-ish solution uses the [SEQUENCE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) function. It's not available in older version of Excel, though. The example below also uses the [LET()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function to make the formula much shorter and easier to follow.

I setup a sample data sheet with `x` in column `A` and `m` in column `B`. I made up number for both column and ended up with 39 values in each. That doesn't really matter but it will help understand the formula. You'll need to change it to match your actual data.

[image: Data sheet]

Here's the formula that gives the end result:

```
=LET(X,A:A,M,B:B,n,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),1,2,6),Xn,INDEX(X,n),Mn,INDEX(M,n),SUMPRODUCT(Xn,Mn)/SUM(Mn))
```

Let's break it down one term at a time. LET() allows us to define values as variables so all but the last term is part of a pair. Here are are those pairs:

- `X,A:A` saves the data range for X. Update this to match your actual data.
- `M,B:B` saves the data range for M. Update this to match your actual data.
- `n,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),1,2,6)` creates an array that counts - in this case - from 2 to however many non-blanks there were in X, only reporting every 6th number. You will likely need to edit this. In my data, the actual *data* in X started at row 2. The resulting array was `2,8,14,20,...`. Key point: The way this is written, it will create an array that counts much higher than your data does because it counts the same number of points but it's counting by 6. In my case, the 39 rows of data that I have became an array of `2,8,14,...224,230,236`. This is fine if and only if you don't have any more data below X. If you do, you'll want to edit this. One option is to set the first term to `COUNTA(X)/6+1` or something similar.
- `Xn,INDEX(X,n)` extracts every nth term from X. If `n` counts much higher than `X` is tall, then this will include data below X. In my case, this was all blank which count as zero so it had no impact.
- `Mn,INDEX(M,n)` extracts every nth term from M. Save caveat as for `Xn`.

And then the last term returns the result:

```
SUMPRODUCT(Xn,Mn)/SUM(Mn)
```

`SUMPRODUCT()` multiplies arrays and then sums the resulting array so it is equivalent to `x1*m1 + x2*m2 + ... + xn*mn`.

Here's a larger screenshot of my data showing some of the interim steps, too.

[image: Results]

This formula is not guaranteed perfect for your use case. It should give you a good start, though. If you use a limited range for X and M (like `A1:A40` instead of `A:A`) but don't change the `SEQUENCE()` parameters accordingly, it'll try to pull data beyond the scope of X and return a #REF! error.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in C1 and copy downwards

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A6, B1:B6) / SUM(B1:B6)
```

Where column A is your x values and B your m values. Mathematically this is a weighted sum of xi, where each xi is weighed with the ratio of mi/mtot. The formula will calculate for the 5 rows beneath the current row (6 including itself).

If you only want every 6th row to show the answer, you can blank out the rows in between:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,6)=0, SUMPRODUCT(A1:A6, B1:B6) / SUM(B1:B6), "")
```